# Подсвечивать места на картинке согласно координатам map - area

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Есть картинка, к ней прописаны через map>area координаты мест для кликов.
Вопрос: можно ли эти места как-то подсвечивать при наведении на них мышкой? Форма подсветки может быть простой (в виде квадрата) или более сложной (что-то вроде tooltip'a).
Идея использовать статические Гугл карты, внутри которых кастомные маркеры. При наведении на которые, будут переходы по ссылкам. Но нужно как-то показать, что это "активные маркеры" на изображении. Поэтому и возникла идея исследовать этот вопрос.

```html
<img class="map" src="https://dummyimage.com/640x640/000/fff" usemap="#image-map">
<map name="image-map">
<area target="_self" alt="test" title="test" href="#close" coords="369,270,415,316" shape="rect">
</map>
```

[Пример статической карты гугла](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/overview):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126616/discussion-on-question-by-needhate------).

Answer (score 4):

Лучше использовать SVG но ваш вопрос о map area - привожу пример с плагином который по сути рисует camvas

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/vJvRnhN/1.jpg" usemap="#image-map" class="map">

  <map name="image-map">
    <area target="" alt="" title="" href="" coords="409,376,233,197" shape="rect">
    <area target="" alt="" title="" href="" coords="342,386,237,386,234,513,257,515,255,482,311,481,311,508,317,516,345,516,345,387" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="" title="" href="" coords="358,389,462,446" shape="rect">
    <area target="" alt="" title="" href="" coords="467,514,366,462" shape="rect">
    <area target="" alt="" title="" href="" coords="563,364,426,203" shape="rect">
    <area target="" alt="" title="" href="" coords="567,414,480,390" shape="rect">
</map>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://projects.davidlynch.org/maphilight/jquery.maphilight.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('.map').maphilight();
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

**Смотреть на весь экран**

Comment: Не ясно как это работает, в дереве ничего не появляется, вроде. Если canvas рисует при наведении, по фокусу на отдельные area берет данные из атрибута и строит поверх фигуру, то почему она не перекрывает фокус? Надо прописывать "не реагирование" на фокус или по всплытию так и само получится?

Comment: @Leonid при mousemove работает же ? заливка появляется ?

Comment: Все работает, я про другое: как?))) Если поверх картинки динамически создается канва, то почему она не мешает событию mouseover или mousemove, или что там еще. Или туплю...

Comment: @Leonid надо скачать скрипт себе и внутри написаны параметры - filColor и так далее - изменить их - даже можешь открыть скрипт и посмотреть в самом низу

Comment: @Leonid эти параметры , даже ты лучше меня знаешь ,  можно вынести отдельно - что бы мозг не парить

Comment: Понял, поковыряюсь вечером))) Все же с помощью SVG это было бы гораздо проще. Потому как канва не очень события мыши ловит на отдельных фигурах, а фигуры SVG по сути те же элементы DOM. Александр же должен объявиться в конце концов)))

Comment: @Leonid разумеется что с SVG проще и самое главное без всяких jQuery и его плагинов

Comment: Да, спасибо! Я видел этот пример с jquery и эту библиотеку. Но нужен чистый js. И вот почему-то в голове у меня была стойкая уверенность, что есть варианты с SVG. А сейчас такое время, когда крупные компании минимизируют свои затраты, в частности и с google картами. И тут уже сеошник ко мне обращается с просьбой, как-то это исследовать, потому как теряем активные клики с переходами.

Answer (score 4):

> Идея использовать статические Гугл карты, внутри которых кастомные
> маркеры. При наведении на которые, будут переходы по ссылкам.

Вариантов решения при использовании SVG может быть несколько.

Вот один из них:

- Копируем SVG карту с https://www.amcharts.com/javascript-maps/
- Если нужно, чтобы при наведении на регион была всплывающая подсказка
  добавляем к path `<title>текст </title>`

```
   <title>      "Mecklenburg-Vorpommern"
    ------------------------------------
    Area • Total -23,174 km2 (8,948 sq mi)
    Capital Schwerin
    ISO 3166 code   DE-MV
   </title>
```

- Подсветка при наведении реализуется CSS:

```
.land:hover {
 fill:dodgerblue;
 stroke:white;
 stroke-width:2px;
 -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
 transform: scale(1.2);
 }
```

- Если нужно разместить маркеры  на определенных участках карты, то
  добавляем svg код маркера в секцию `<defs>` и используем его многократно,
  позиционируя маркер на карте координатами `x,y`

```
<a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/">
       <use href="#marker"  x="200"/>
    </a>  
        <a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svg">
          <use href="#marker"  x="400" y="100"/>
       </a>
```

***Ссылки рабочие в пределах RuSO/ Пощелкайте, посмотрите переходы***

Ниже полный код:

```css
.land
 {
 fill: #CCCCCC;
 fill-opacity: 1;
 stroke:white;
 stroke-opacity: 1;
 stroke-width:0.5;
 transform-origin: center center;
 transform-box: fill-box;
 transition:  1s;
            }
.land:hover {
 fill:dodgerblue;
 stroke:white;
 stroke-width:2px;
 -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
 transform: scale(1.2);
 } 
  use path{
fill:inherit;
stroke:inherit;
 }

use:hover {
fill:red;
 pointer-events:all;
}
```

```html
<!-- (c) ammap.com | SVG map of Germany -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" 
  width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 600 800" style="border:0px solid">
<defs>
<g id="marker" transform="scale(4)">
    <path  d="M9.831 4.916c0 2.714-3.538 8.487-4.913 9.867C3.437 13.307 0 7.631 0 4.916S2.201 0 4.916 0s4.915 2.201 4.915 4.916z"/>
    <circle cx="4.912" cy="4.916" r="2.932"  fill="#E7EDEF"/>
</g>    
</defs> 
     
         <g> 
        
           <title>"Berlin"</title>
        <path id="DE-BE" title="Berlin" class="land" d="M485.13,257.7L485.2,257.74L485.2,257.74L488.12,260.2L487.19,265.7L496.58,272.25L493.65,278.32L503.07,281.3L496.02,292.2L495.77,288.21L485.31,286.24L484.46,283.74L481.5,284.77L481.48,288.32L473.68,284.09L462.87,286.78L460.54,284.53L465.46,274.35L462.28,273.56L463.02,266.3L468.62,266.16L468.88,261.95L471.62,262.01L472.85,258.49L477.73,262.39L484.8,259.5L484.07,257.58L484.07,257.58L484.98,257.05L484.98,257.05L485.36,257.16L485.36,257.16z"/>
        
        </g>

       
       
        <g> 
          
           <title>"Brandenburg"</title>
        <path id="DE-BB"  class="land" d="M344.3,209.85l8.02,1.19l1.8,-3.16l7.08,1.66l1.2,-8.96l7.4,-3.75l4.06,2.84l5.54,-0.75l-1.38,-3.02l4.06,0.48l10.37,-5.54l1.53,-7.65l7.88,3.47l3.88,-2.05l1.78,3.73l8.55,2.52l3.33,5.44l13.8,-0.45l1.43,2.9l4.58,0.3l0.85,3.82l12.47,-1.39l-1.35,2.75l3.96,0.87l9.22,-8.82l5.16,3.63l4.42,-6.82l6.74,3.41l1.96,-5.34l3.03,0.62l2.39,-2.91l1.82,-8.42l4.82,-1.24l5.59,-7.61l6.29,-0.43l-2.43,-3.12l1.17,-4.79l5.37,5.8l2.49,8.85l20.64,-0.67l-0.89,7.39L524.76,195l10.43,0.28l3.57,-5.47l6.01,-2.08l0,0l2.24,7.22l-4.5,6.74l-0.82,12.83l-13.97,12.39l1.04,8.08l-2.41,4.88l14.57,9.2l18.26,18.7l-2.18,4.03l1.88,4.48l-6.32,9.97l3.71,12.6l7.73,3.9l-2.04,12.46l4.91,5.25l-4.07,16.95l-6.63,7.67l10.62,17.16l-1.73,7.98l0,0l-2.12,-1.61l-1.12,4.56l-4.09,0.3l-3.03,-3.09l-11.42,3.93l-3.51,3.93l-12.47,-4.08l-3.16,6.77l-3.47,0.11l1.82,3.13l-4.07,7.31l-2.52,-2.38l-11.84,3.46l-14.67,-0.7l-9.17,-8.53l-1.34,2.87l-3.49,-1.17l-3.59,5.3l-3.34,-1.15l-2.51,-3.24l2.05,-9.8l-4.06,-4.59l1.12,-2.54l-6.89,-5.4l0,0l8.48,-7.22l-2.99,-16.74l-6.2,0.89l0.25,-2.97l-4.62,0.05l-0.97,-3.69h-6.75l-0.47,-3.38l-4.14,0.53l-6.92,-5.08l-3.75,3.09l-4.62,-0.36l-3.86,-4.92l-2.84,1.76l-13.81,-15.78l5.04,-6.12l-3.3,-2.48l3.94,-9.8l-2.16,-7.13l3.66,-6.58l-5.64,-4.62l-3.65,2.66l0.29,-3.85l-2.94,0.24l1.64,-9.97l3.81,-0.42l-1.96,-9.34l3.75,-9.1l-1.54,-5.94l-2.51,-1.75l-4.4,2.67l-0.12,-4.27l-9.2,1.93l-9.36,-3.58l0.63,-4.53l-6.5,-3.88l-3.03,1.23l-1.1,-3.25l-3.23,-0.37l0.88,-2.82l-2.52,0.24l0,0l-9.3,-4.54l-7.29,2.44L344.3,209.85zM484.8,259.5l-7.07,2.89l-4.88,-3.9l-1.23,3.52l-2.74,-0.06l-0.25,4.21l-5.6,0.15l-0.75,7.26l3.18,0.78l-4.92,10.19l2.33,2.25l10.8,-2.69l7.8,4.23l0.02,-3.55l2.96,-1.03l0.85,2.5l10.45,1.97l0.25,3.99l7.05,-10.9l-9.42,-2.97l2.93,-6.08l-9.39,-6.55l0.93,-5.5l-2.92,-2.46l0,0l0.17,-0.58l0,0l-0.38,-0.1l0,0l-0.91,0.52L484.8,259.5z"/>
      
        </g>
        
        <g> 
           <title>"Bremen"</title>
        <path id="DE-HB"  class="land" d="M167.33,198.78l0.72,-0.1l0,0l6.18,1.69l-1.23,2.18l2.79,2.05l13.14,0.83l2.17,3.48l5.17,-2.19l2.46,2.73l-2.24,1.09l2.65,2.01l-0.55,5.41l-2.93,3.42l-4.4,-2.78l-2.81,2.1l-3.19,-3.5l-3.43,1.47l-6.32,-13.54l-6.92,-3.24l0,0l0,0l0,0l-1.31,-3.24l0,0L167.33,198.78zM169.27,158.35l8.9,-0.44l-2.71,3.76l0.96,8.47l-3.74,1l-1.17,-3.99l0,0l1.42,-1.84L169.27,158.35z"/>
        </g> 
        <g> 
           <title>"Hamburg"</title>
        <path id="DE-HH"  class="land" d="M246.33,163.56L248.94,155.53L253.09,160.38L257.57,153.33L262.18,153.98L263.46,150.25L267.7,150.59L268.7,146.04L274.31,144.08L275.84,145.66L272.71,150.58L277.67,155.3L276.21,160.45L273.15,161.8L273.86,167.23L277,167.42L284.34,175.11L283.21,176.76L283.21,176.76L278.78,180.74L274.68,180.74L266.87,173.56L262.59,178.61L258.16,178.86L257.4,174.35L254.73,177.15L251.25,173.6L249.16,163.92z"/>
        </g>
        <g> 
           <title>"Hesse"</title>
        <path id="DE-HE"  class="land" d="M228.57,363.63L239.71,364.71L243.77,370.74L239.94,370.01L241.01,373.34L238.39,372.36L237.13,376.89L240.77,381.62L240.85,386.94L236.65,388.67L236.04,392.66L233.68,392.15L235.59,394.41L246.59,399.46L249.05,395.24L246.92,396.99L244.56,392.48L250.72,390.28L250.53,387.99L254.96,391.71L254.04,387.33L257.29,387.02L258.96,391.32L258.96,391.32L261.78,400.55L267.08,401.15L267.92,406.43L278.65,410.58L276.22,417.97L274.12,413.9L271.17,415.3L274.68,417.62L272.55,423.36L276.66,425.82L276.6,428.59L266.07,428.06L264.81,431.25L267.6,434.96L260.4,435.21L262.79,436.27L261.76,438.66L264.33,437.27L267.42,441.23L265.3,446.07L260.55,447.42L255.68,465.57L261,466.66L260.6,462.87L267,462.49L268.82,467.35L265.93,468.54L266.23,478L266.23,478L264.73,482.94L257.28,489.23L248.36,487.1L247.38,498.61L241.49,502.46L242.14,506.21L231.68,505.4L232.45,519.97L227.46,520.98L223.4,516.33L213.92,514.58L209.49,520.27L207.43,516.82L199.68,520.26L198.33,524.58L201.66,525.34L202.97,529.97L200.98,531.51L202.13,544.72L205.3,544.47L205.58,549.91L208.4,550.81L206.67,553.11L209.25,554.87L204.1,566.8L206.4,570.93L206.4,570.93L204.44,572.16L207.85,576.87L196.72,578.15L196.62,582.87L190.25,588.76L187.17,587.29L188.71,581.63L191.97,581.76L193.37,578.24L189.11,579.32L188.52,576.11L180.8,575.02L180.19,566.45L174,567.78L175.32,574.53L171.82,577.14L166.36,570.37L162.99,570.34L162.99,570.34L158.96,559.7L166.61,552.81L163.07,552.18L160.28,546.83L156.62,531.69L147.81,525.89L128.79,532.15L121.66,523.67L125.77,521.07L126.65,516.79L131.62,519.2L131.78,515.09L128.71,512.68L130.36,509.21L135.33,505.79L138.18,507.96L138.42,502.49L142.89,503.54L143.7,499.7L139.92,492.22L133.79,488.56L136.77,484.32L135.78,477.16L138.86,473.89L142.66,476.29L144.72,474.55L144.01,461.08L144.01,461.08L146.74,456.2L144.6,450.64L153.07,441.46L158.94,443.44L165.39,437.61L165.28,432.87L170.31,427.46L168.09,421.33L181.98,418.31L180.44,415.53L184.98,408.27L182.08,401.69L174.03,404.39L171.58,401.32L175.59,395.35L180.31,391.22L195.87,389.93L196.45,386.03L192.88,380.49L201,376.79L205.64,379.11L205.92,384.27L213.6,382.79L223.52,369.32L221.31,366.92z"/>
        </g>
         <g> 
           <title>      "Mecklenburg-Vorpommern"
    ------------------------------------
    Area • Total -23,174 km2 (8,948 sq mi)
    Capital Schwerin
    ISO 3166 code   DE-MV
           </title>
        <path id="DE-MV"  class="land" d="M506.34,97.76l4.16,7.29l9.15,5.19l13.36,13.4l-2.67,1.61l1.77,4.97l-11.17,-0.75l-6.21,3.27l-0.74,-3.29l-1.09,3.36l-5.44,-0.79l7.1,-6.32l-1.86,-8.65l3.52,0.01l-0.37,5.89l1.59,-2.95l3.65,2.11l0.45,-4.57l-4.91,-8.62l-3.86,0.08l1.03,5.1l-0.28,-2.04l-3.95,3.73l-0.23,-5.16l-5.59,3.1l2.7,-9.62l-4.04,-5.48L506.34,97.76zM435.9,69.27l1.61,1.44l-3.42,-0.11L435.9,69.27zM424.89,63.46l2.05,3.08l22.51,0.9l0.62,1.97l-7.87,2.04l-10.53,-1.85l-6.48,6.64l10.89,-5.09l-1.95,4.42l1.53,-3.05l2.24,3.08l3.26,-2.78l1.61,5.67l7.15,-7.56l6.79,-2.47l-0.25,4.24l4.26,3.17l0.76,9.39l4.76,1.33L464,88.41l2.73,-1.42l6.5,3.42l2.33,5.54l2.84,0.23l-3.42,2.36l6.37,-1.55l-2.24,3.23l1.8,-1.25l3.69,7.51l2.08,0.08l-0.64,-4.17l14.05,-4.86l-0.8,2.15l6.6,5.51l-3.72,7.61l10.86,11.49l-5.72,4.9l-0.46,3.65l18.19,11.06l10.48,-0.91l-3.31,4.93l4.15,1.7l8.41,38.14l0,0l-6.01,2.08l-3.57,5.47L524.76,195l8.17,-10.36l0.89,-7.39l-20.64,0.67l-2.49,-8.85l-5.37,-5.8l-1.17,4.79l2.43,3.12l-6.29,0.43l-5.59,7.61l-4.82,1.24l-1.82,8.42l-2.39,2.91l-3.03,-0.62l-1.96,5.34l-6.74,-3.41l-4.42,6.82l-5.16,-3.63l-9.22,8.82l-3.96,-0.87l1.35,-2.75l-12.47,1.39l-0.85,-3.82l-4.58,-0.3l-1.43,-2.9l-13.8,0.45l-3.33,-5.44l-8.55,-2.52l-1.78,-3.73l-3.88,2.05l-7.88,-3.47l-1.53,7.65l-10.37,5.54l-4.06,-0.48l1.38,3.02l-5.54,0.75l-4.06,-2.84l-7.4,3.75l-1.2,8.96l-7.08,-1.66l-1.8,3.16l-8.02,-1.19l0,0l-5.31,-1.53l0.82,-4.63l-6.83,-3.55l-6.5,-12.73l-4.42,-1.59l-5.27,4.67l-8.65,-7.03l-6.65,0.68l0,0l2.42,-9.56l12.25,-6.35l-0.17,-6.55l5.62,0.36l2.65,-8.29l-1.86,-5.47l-4.63,-0.29l-5.85,-5.36l0.85,-13.02l6.93,-5.62l1.96,2.87l3.45,-1.03l-4.59,-1.62l0.66,-3.64l0,0l8.62,-5.35l8.99,-0.97l5.08,3.39l-0.13,5.23l4.98,-2.57l7.9,6.75l1.52,-7.62l-2.42,0.9l-0.06,-4.29L354.8,120l-2.75,-0.41l-0.14,-3.94l6.66,-2.2l-0.02,5.96l1.88,-6.97l3.46,-0.25l3.28,-6.13l-1.35,-1.37l-4.67,5.94l-0.27,-2.75l9.71,-8.54l10.65,0.8l17.71,-4.2l3.87,-5.85l9.57,-6.35L424.89,63.46zM464.13,50.28l-5.16,15.79l2.21,-14.48L464.13,50.28zM482.31,41.36l-3.58,5.45l2.77,6.09l13.64,-0.74l2.81,2.3l-6.61,12.74l2.47,4.76l3.76,0.38l5.99,6.49l-3.54,7.89l-0.54,-3l-3.58,-0.14l3.71,-3.18l-5.99,1.1l4.77,-3.81l-4.41,2.36L492,77.51l-5.2,1.21l-9.55,7.89l0.34,2.53l0.46,-1.89l3.38,1.09l-1.64,3.56l-6.46,-3.18l1.98,0.57l0.78,-3.61l-4.17,2.7l-4.35,-1.79l-0.39,-2.88l-3.42,1.6l2.85,-2l-4.49,-3.49l0.83,-4.21l8.47,-1.45l-3.12,-4.98l-3.91,0.79l1.8,-3.63l-3.64,0.9l3.07,-4.87l3.67,0.83l-1.8,4.08l4.56,-3.56l-2.7,-0.61l0.18,-2.75l-3.88,0.31L464,56.46l6.37,-0.96l3.81,4.46l-0.45,-4.24l3.66,-2.99l-1.02,3.48l2.34,-1.22l2.35,7.22l2.45,2.46l3.33,-1.08l0.54,-9.21l-4.2,1.51l-4.83,-6.9l-8.04,6.07l2.62,-9.48l-7.86,9.54l5.41,-10.88L482.31,41.36z"/> 
        </g> 
         <g> 
           <title>"Lower Saxony"</title>
        <path id="DE-NI"  class="land" d="M60.4,159.06l-6.04,1.6l1.74,3.04l-5.74,-3.15l6.06,-3.78L60.4,159.06zM97.87,144.43l2.35,1.9l-4.99,-0.89L97.87,144.43zM109.16,141.9l3.35,1.47l-10.55,2.34l0.91,-3.27L109.16,141.9zM118.39,139.44l6,1.1l-9.43,1.86L118.39,139.44zM129.41,138.01l4.77,2.17l-7.91,-1.23L129.41,138.01zM179.97,127.51l5.23,5.99l7.84,1.37l8.04,-1.86l-1.01,-3.55l0,0l13.06,-0.56l6.67,2.83l12.21,17.13l2.84,8.25l11.48,6.46l0,0l2.83,0.35l2.08,9.69l3.48,3.54l2.68,-2.8l0.75,4.5l4.44,-0.25l4.28,-5.05l7.81,7.18h4.1l4.43,-3.98l0,0l18.28,7.39l0,0l6.65,-0.68l8.65,7.03l5.27,-4.67l4.42,1.59l6.5,12.73l6.83,3.55l-0.82,4.63l5.31,1.53l0,0l4.55,7.01l7.29,-2.44l9.3,4.54l0,0l-2.7,3.89l-2.98,-0.7l-0.45,6.88l-12.05,6.6l-19.61,-3.49l-4.16,6.16l-11.02,1.12l1.98,13.53l1.93,-0.26l5.79,11.2l3.61,-1.46l-2.47,5.88l4.52,7.55l-4.03,0.18l-0.71,3.44l8.97,8.94l-5.84,3.47l6.5,11.69l-4.59,3.15l2.97,2.63l-0.96,4.01l-6.47,3.21l1.43,4.79l-16.92,0.71l-8.8,4.69l5.67,4.84l-2.42,1.99l2.34,4.9l-4.6,4.32l-0.2,3.87l8.03,17.4l0,0l-3.96,2.24l1.14,6.25l-3.23,-2.15l-5.53,2.62l-5.49,-3.91l-4.01,0.48l-4.54,9.57l-4.16,2.37l-2,-1.58l-3.07,5.57l-5.45,1.37l-1.4,-1.95l-7.55,6.33l0,0l-1.67,-4.3l-3.25,0.31l0.92,4.38l-4.44,-3.72l0.19,2.28l-6.15,2.2l2.35,4.52l2.14,-1.75l-2.47,4.21l-11,-5.05l-1.91,-2.26l2.36,0.51l0.61,-3.99l4.2,-1.72l-0.08,-5.32l-3.63,-4.73l1.26,-4.53l2.61,0.98l-1.06,-3.33l3.82,0.73l-4.05,-6.03l-11.14,-1.08l0,0l-4.86,-0.35l0.01,-9.56l4.54,-5.24l0.89,-6.85l-8.64,0.73l1.04,-5.53l-4.3,-2.48l0.06,-4.22l-4.21,1.27l-2.11,-2.07l1.21,-9.22l-3.83,-2.61l1.27,-3.61l-9.09,-0.57l-1.66,-6.2l3.7,1.13l-0.5,-4.2l2.61,-0.77l-7.08,-5.01l10.03,-12.94l-1.83,-4.11l2.7,-3.43l-2.38,-2.18l-3,-0.29l-7.38,10.27l-5.19,1.29l-9.48,-0.64l-0.33,-11.32l-3.23,-2.83l-6.02,3.41l-3.47,-1.36l-5.41,7.04l-7.26,-1.47l0.85,5.74l8.13,4.31l-0.09,15.3l4.74,3.12l-7.04,7.64l-7.68,-2.54l-5.97,6.44l-10.21,0.4l-3.27,3.45l-6.11,-4.99l7.84,-3.25l1.17,-4.9l-7.94,-4.33l3.57,-6.49l-1.59,-3.61l3.82,-0.74l-3.51,-5.79l-14.26,-3.71l-1.57,-5.4l-5.14,-2.29l-2.74,4.46l2.44,1.08l-1.28,4.74l-18.29,11.56l-14.88,2.32l0,0l-2.39,-5.02l3.02,-8.69l-5.28,-9.79l-3.12,3.39l-11.76,-2.84l-3.81,-2.53l-1.13,-6.92l5.53,-1.08l-3.48,-6.68l2.53,-2.25l19.34,0.57l2.08,-21.73l8.28,-16.56l-2.42,-13.97l3.04,-4.26l-1.13,-6.84l2.29,-8.14l4.02,-0.19l-18.76,-2.27l1.21,-20.46l4.21,3.68l-3.7,-3.96l4.04,2.69l2.51,-3.23l-3.45,-3.97l9.89,-9.75l7.43,-1.81l10.45,1.73l11.38,-5.21l0.02,2.11l6.55,-1.16l1.8,-2.54l-1.58,2.92l13.81,-0.12l1.09,7.07l4.65,0.61l3.51,10.82l-7.1,3.26l0.18,3.1l8.78,7.68l4.21,-0.14l2.93,-5.51l-0.19,-6.81l-5.28,0.11l3.42,-9.74l3.58,-0.12l8.07,6.35l3.47,-0.63l2.41,3.76l0,0l1.17,3.99l3.74,-1l-0.96,-8.47l2.71,-3.76l-8.9,0.44l0,0l-2.48,-9.53l4.18,-12.99l4.08,-7.1L179.97,127.51zM167.27,198.66L167.27,198.66l1.31,3.24l6.92,3.24l6.32,13.54l3.43,-1.47l3.19,3.5l2.81,-2.1l4.4,2.78l2.93,-3.42l0.55,-5.41l-2.65,-2.01l2.24,-1.09l-2.46,-2.73l-5.17,2.19l-2.17,-3.48l-13.14,-0.83l-2.79,-2.05l1.23,-2.18l-6.18,-1.69L167.27,198.66z"/>
        </g> 
        <g> 
           <title>"North Rhine-Westphalia"</title>
        <path id="DE-NW"  class="land" d="M76.38,302.23L91.26,299.91L109.56,288.35L110.84,283.61L108.4,282.53L111.14,278.07L116.27,280.36L117.84,285.76L132.1,289.47L135.61,295.25L131.79,295.99L133.38,299.6L129.81,306.09L137.75,310.42L136.58,315.32L128.74,318.57L134.84,323.57L138.11,320.12L148.32,319.71L154.29,313.27L161.97,315.81L169,308.17L164.26,305.05L164.35,289.75L156.22,285.44L155.37,279.7L162.63,281.17L168.04,274.14L171.52,275.49L177.54,272.09L180.77,274.92L181.1,286.24L190.58,286.88L195.77,285.58L203.15,275.32L206.15,275.61L208.53,277.79L205.83,281.23L207.66,285.33L197.63,298.27L204.71,303.28L202.09,304.04L202.59,308.25L198.89,307.12L200.54,313.31L209.63,313.88L208.36,317.5L212.19,320.1L210.98,329.32L213.09,331.4L217.31,330.13L217.25,334.35L221.55,336.83L220.51,342.36L229.15,341.63L228.26,348.48L223.71,353.72L223.71,363.28L228.57,363.63L228.57,363.63L221.31,366.92L223.52,369.32L213.6,382.79L205.92,384.27L205.64,379.11L201,376.79L192.88,380.49L196.45,386.03L195.87,389.93L180.31,391.22L175.59,395.35L171.58,401.32L174.03,404.39L182.08,401.69L184.98,408.27L180.44,415.53L181.98,418.31L168.09,421.33L170.31,427.46L165.28,432.87L165.39,437.61L158.94,443.44L153.07,441.46L144.6,450.64L146.74,456.2L144.01,461.08L144.01,461.08L138.65,459.88L134.03,452.04L134.05,444.96L125.1,441.26L126.51,436.67L122.85,435.21L119.22,437.66L120.94,445.04L114.44,447.46L115.13,451.42L110.08,455.63L96.22,457.75L93.72,465.7L85.91,467.3L85.17,464.78L81.7,469.61L79.69,468.42L78.04,471.05L75.88,469.03L72.18,473.18L67.87,473.6L67.91,476.25L64.81,476.88L65.96,482.74L63.25,484.33L59.61,480.43L56.06,482.31L59.52,493.57L53.31,496L51.25,492.58L49.29,495.2L46.99,490.88L37.45,495.98L34.92,490.75L34.4,497.38L34.4,497.38L30.39,491.64L32.63,486.02L31,480.75L23.07,480.09L20.03,475.41L25.8,466.98L19.96,466.99L16.38,457.62L11.14,457.68L10.3,452.21L6.95,449.92L10.22,448.04L9.84,444.94L13.35,444.87L14.68,437.33L9.87,436.02L10.22,431.03L2.1,431.94L0.03,424.56L3.1,422.7L6,425.79L9.29,420.15L19.74,413.5L17.53,411.91L19.17,409.75L13.86,412L13.18,404.88L23.01,392.69L22.22,377.36L14.41,367.78L16.02,362.62L10.66,360.78L11.4,356.38L5.75,354.14L8.02,349.6L5.13,345.39L12.71,341.21L19.2,343.66L16.2,337.39L34.27,345.09L33.62,340.22L38.56,342.38L52.24,335.8L55.28,337.7L61.53,328.65L52.4,323.19L52.83,319.98L55.56,319.49L57.1,315L63.11,314.79L71.34,303.9z"/>
        </g> 
                
         <g> 
           <title>"Saxony"</title>
        <path id="DE-SN" title="Saxony" class="land" d="M409.06,420.36L403.51,415.05L403.77,405.34L400.41,396.85L403.55,395.99L400.5,382.43L404.19,379.5L405.85,372.11L418.09,370.21L419.2,367.43L421.97,368.9L430.88,365.69L429.82,367.29L435.07,361.75L440.17,363.52L444.84,359.68L451.1,364.45L453.48,361.28L458.17,363.61L458.17,363.61L465.06,369.01L463.95,371.54L468.01,376.13L465.95,385.93L468.46,389.17L471.8,390.33L475.4,385.03L478.89,386.2L480.23,383.33L489.4,391.86L504.07,392.57L515.91,389.1L518.43,391.49L522.5,384.18L520.68,381.05L524.16,380.93L527.32,374.16L539.79,378.24L543.3,374.3L554.72,370.38L557.76,373.47L561.84,373.17L562.96,368.61L565.08,370.21L565.08,370.21L565.46,375.9L579.17,381.68L580.87,394.65L584.98,401.69L580.86,421.64L569.28,447.49L558.02,443.73L559.96,436.33L554.58,437.64L556.68,430.81L550.29,427.18L550.48,424.72L549.9,427.06L544.64,427.52L537.82,423.85L535.1,430.7L539.27,430.96L538.35,434L543.85,435.87L543.2,439.71L535.53,440.02L523.44,448.37L512.17,450.25L512.04,455.14L509.38,456.85L488.35,459.06L488.24,465.7L484.54,469.3L478.5,464.63L475.36,471.66L470.54,470.42L467.23,479.28L456.82,478.64L456.11,484.77L451.41,489.31L443.25,483.66L442.67,486.5L441.71,484.71L437.9,486.39L436.06,489.9L433.92,487.95L423.7,489.94L412.12,505.41L412.5,512.26L409.51,511.86L409.75,507.48L406.3,504.99L407.28,502.51L403.83,502.33L402.79,497.38L397.47,497.79L397.47,497.79L389.6,494.54L389.97,490.78L386.17,487.29L386.17,487.29L384.37,484.79L387.82,484.27L388.86,480.96L382.78,475.87L391.14,466.23L394.64,474.55L396.15,472.01L401.44,471.96L400.58,466.68L403.18,468.31L403.78,465.78L407.84,466.63L411.24,463.28L407.72,460.17L407.97,455.85L405.43,455.76L409.46,451.27L407,447.48L413.15,447.22L414.87,444.14L419.12,445.23L421.83,440.04L432.72,437.54L429.76,429.79L423.35,427.71L423.1,423.08L412.5,419.03z"/>
        </g> 
         <g> 
           <title>"Saxony-Anhalt"
             
           </title>
        <path id="DE-ST" title="Saxony-Anhalt" class="land" d="M365.45,218.95L367.97,218.71L367.09,221.53L370.32,221.9L371.42,225.16L374.45,223.93L380.95,227.81L380.32,232.33L389.68,235.92L398.88,233.99L399,238.25L403.4,235.59L405.91,237.34L407.45,243.27L403.7,252.38L405.66,261.72L401.86,262.14L400.21,272.11L403.15,271.87L402.87,275.71L406.51,273.05L412.15,277.67L408.49,284.25L410.65,291.37L406.71,301.18L410.01,303.66L404.97,309.78L418.78,325.56L421.61,323.81L425.47,328.72L430.09,329.08L433.84,326L440.76,331.08L444.91,330.55L445.38,333.93L452.13,333.93L453.1,337.62L457.72,337.57L457.46,340.54L463.67,339.65L466.65,356.39L458.17,363.61L458.17,363.61L453.48,361.28L451.1,364.45L444.84,359.68L440.17,363.52L435.07,361.75L429.82,367.29L430.88,365.69L421.97,368.9L419.2,367.43L418.09,370.21L405.85,372.11L404.19,379.5L400.5,382.43L403.55,395.99L400.41,396.85L403.77,405.34L403.51,415.05L409.06,420.36L409.06,420.36L406.94,425.62L409.56,427.41L404.76,435.61L402.78,431.91L392.16,432.77L384.1,423.91L375.7,425.21L369.96,418.22L358.26,419.09L357.31,409.95L350.71,407.1L357.69,399.43L352.63,390.75L347.7,387.76L326.79,386.99L323.84,374.77L320.02,370.61L320.54,368.2L322.79,369.28L322.26,366.55L308.21,364.11L308.21,364.11L300.18,346.71L300.39,342.85L304.98,338.52L302.64,333.62L305.06,331.63L299.4,326.79L308.2,322.1L325.12,321.39L323.69,316.6L330.16,313.39L331.12,309.38L328.15,306.74L332.74,303.59L326.25,291.89L332.08,288.43L323.11,279.48L323.82,276.04L327.85,275.86L323.33,268.31L325.79,262.43L322.18,263.89L316.39,252.69L314.46,252.95L312.48,239.42L323.5,238.31L327.66,232.14L347.27,235.63L359.32,229.03L359.76,222.15L362.75,222.84z"/> 
        </g> 
        <g> 
           <title>"Schleswig-Holstein"
           ------------------------------------
    Area • Total -15,763.18 km2 (6,086.20 sq mi)
    Capital Kiel
    ISO 3166 code   DE-SH
           </title>
        <path id="DE-SH"  class="land" d="M166.82,66.59l2.35,2.45l-1.94,1.67l-2.67,-4.29L166.82,66.59zM332.49,58.08l9.41,2.94l5.37,11.14l-7.81,-2.19l-4.48,2.14l-2.14,-4.95l-4.11,0.5l1.58,1.6l-2.51,-1.5l1.31,-7.3L332.49,58.08zM167.37,57.79l-0.91,4.28l-1.17,-5.25L167.37,57.79zM180.99,55.13l-0.17,6.25l-5.39,1.13L173.59,58L180.99,55.13zM171.44,52.84l1.27,2.23l-4.19,-2.04L171.44,52.84zM160.46,46.18l0.94,2.71l-2.42,0.45l-4.45,-6.2l4.47,-5.15l-1.37,2.73L160.46,46.18zM169.54,33.33l3.91,1.16l-1.25,7.3l-10.71,-2.42l1.81,-5.03L169.54,33.33zM163.97,0.73l1.77,0.6l-4.43,0.14l2.81,3.28l-5.56,5.21l1.11,7.58l3.58,2.32l11.07,-1.05l2.19,-2.65l19.86,0.96l18.37,5.74l0.89,4.46l2.86,0.97l3.16,0.14l4.19,-4.6l1.73,5.88l11.27,-9.7l-0.47,5.07l12.03,3.77l3.84,4.81l3.35,-1.14l-0.01,-3.72l3.27,1.96l5.13,10.28l-2.49,-0.09l2.35,1.88l-0.49,13.02l-4,5.24L253,64.29l2.07,2.87l16.57,-4.02l4.75,3.21l-4.27,15.75l3.28,-1.77l2.68,-9.43l6.21,-2.37l17.55,7.84l6.6,6.44l5.49,-0.85l8.99,-7.58l6.01,1.51l5.56,-3.27l0.84,2.82l-4.37,2.11l2.28,16.93l-14.19,12.24l-3.89,-2.32l-3.69,6.28l2.12,5.41l5.44,0.71l2.12,3.81l0,0l-0.66,3.64l4.59,1.62l-3.45,1.03l-1.96,-2.87l-6.93,5.62l-0.85,13.02l5.85,5.36l4.63,0.29l1.86,5.47l-2.65,8.29l-5.62,-0.36l0.17,6.55l-12.25,6.35l-2.42,9.56l0,0l-18.28,-7.39l0,0l1.13,-1.65l-7.34,-7.69l-3.15,-0.18l-0.71,-5.44l3.07,-1.35l1.46,-5.15l-4.96,-4.72l3.12,-4.92l-1.53,-1.58l-5.61,1.96l-1,4.55l-4.24,-0.34l-1.27,3.73l-4.62,-0.65l-4.48,7.05l-4.14,-4.86l-2.61,8.04l0,0l-11.48,-6.46l-2.84,-8.25l-12.21,-17.13l-6.67,-2.83l-13.06,0.56l0,0l-6.27,-6.5l-1.5,-7.38l-4.91,-2.29l4.75,-2.33l5.01,1.18l1.7,-2.38l-3.64,-7.99l-4.47,1.29l-3.12,-5.67l1.94,-12.13l-8.27,-0.65l-2.03,2.44L173,82.47l1.71,-5.06l2.16,1.62l3.1,-1.96l-5.35,-1.38l0.8,-2.11l16.15,-2.02l11.39,-7.45l-3.03,-0.39l-1.19,-4.4l-5.54,6.62l-5.8,-1.17l5.53,-13.43l-0.83,-1.84l-4.22,1.34l2.68,-2.28l-10.42,-11.71l-5.97,-17.46L162.4,23.4l-4.71,-3.58l-3.78,14.22l1.04,-17.71l6.25,-15.67L163.97,0.73z"/> 
        </g> 
        <g>
          <title>"Thuringia"</title>
        <path id="DE-TH"  class="land" d="M308.21,364.11L322.26,366.55L322.79,369.28L320.54,368.2L320.02,370.61L323.84,374.77L326.79,386.99L347.7,387.76L352.63,390.75L357.69,399.43L350.71,407.1L357.31,409.95L358.26,419.09L369.96,418.22L375.7,425.21L384.1,423.91L392.16,432.77L402.78,431.91L404.76,435.61L409.56,427.41L406.94,425.62L409.06,420.36L409.06,420.36L412.5,419.03L423.1,423.08L423.35,427.71L429.76,429.79L432.72,437.54L421.83,440.04L419.12,445.23L414.87,444.14L413.15,447.22L407,447.48L409.46,451.27L405.43,455.76L407.97,455.85L407.72,460.17L411.24,463.28L407.84,466.63L403.78,465.78L403.18,468.31L400.58,466.68L401.44,471.96L396.15,472.01L394.64,474.55L391.14,466.23L382.78,475.87L388.86,480.96L387.82,484.27L384.37,484.79L386.17,487.29L386.17,487.29L379.89,490.67L376.99,487.67L360.59,492.12L358.09,486.59L355.54,487.62L354.1,485.17L354.77,478.48L349.35,477.53L345.84,482.04L343.09,481.72L345.43,493.56L343.32,502.7L336.61,501L337.36,496.54L334.65,492.94L326.34,494.82L323.22,490.38L316.62,490.37L309.05,495L309.21,497.5L317.46,502.02L317.53,505.09L310.2,504.4L309.26,509.04L302.29,506.5L301.79,496.22L298.27,493.2L294.9,494.07L292.4,489.44L288.76,490.22L284.63,480.24L278.37,478.53L276.56,474.22L272.67,475.36L270.48,473.26L266.23,478L266.23,478L265.93,468.54L268.82,467.35L267,462.49L260.6,462.87L261,466.66L255.68,465.57L260.55,447.42L265.3,446.07L267.42,441.23L264.33,437.27L261.76,438.66L262.79,436.27L260.4,435.21L267.6,434.96L264.81,431.25L266.07,428.06L276.6,428.59L276.66,425.82L272.55,423.36L274.68,417.62L271.17,415.3L274.12,413.9L276.22,417.97L278.65,410.58L267.92,406.43L267.08,401.15L261.78,400.55L258.96,391.32L258.96,391.32L266.51,385L267.91,386.94L273.36,385.58L276.44,380.01L278.43,381.59L282.59,379.22L287.13,369.65L291.14,369.17L296.62,373.08L302.16,370.46L305.39,372.61L304.25,366.35z"/>
    </g>  
    <a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/">
       <use href="#marker"  x="200"/>
    </a>  
        <a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svg">
          <use href="#marker"  x="400" y="100"/>
       </a>  
  <a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css">
          <use href="#marker"  x="220" y="200"/>
  </a>   
       <a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/28748/alexandr-tt">
          <use href="#marker"  x="50" y="350"/>
      </a>    
 <a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/195336/needhate">
          <use href="#marker"  x="350" y="270"/>
  </a>        
</svg>
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что изображение представлено в виде картинки. Это именно статическая карта, например, как вот здесь: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY&zoom=13&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C40.702147,-74.015794&markers=color:green%7Clabel:G%7C40.711614,-74.012318&markers=color:red%7Clabel:C%7C40.718217,-73.998284&key=AIzaSyA3kg7YWugGl1lTXmAmaBGPNhDW9pEh5bo&signature=GJnbP6sQrFY1ce8IsvG2WR2P0Jw= 
И маркеры там представлены соответственно как на изображении из документации гугл.
Обновил пример в вопросе.

Comment: @NeedHate всё это легко решается. Картинка добавляется с помощью svg <image> маркеры могут быть как растровые, так и векторные и позиционировать их можно как в моем ответе.  Хотите дам второй ответ?

Comment: @NeedHate и что с ним делать, если его нельзя из-за приватности использовать?

Comment: ))) Его можно использовать, но там есть токен на доступ к картам. Там пример, полного использования идеи, на какие элементы статической карты наводить.

Comment: @NeedHate можно ссылку удалить, забрал